# Не устанавливаются NPM пакеты

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет! Пытаюсь установить NPM пакеты, но вылезают такие баги. Делал команды `npm upgrade`, `npm cache` , отдельно пытался установить `npm i node-gyp`, но все бестолку: ошибки те же. Уже вбил почти все команды.
Знаю, что надо что-то из этого обновить, но начинаю с конца обновлять, так ничего не устанавливается. Папка `node modules` появляется во время инстала, но после ошибок - исчезает.

```
$ npm i
npm WARN deprecated set-value@2.0.0: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated mixin-deep@1.3.1: Critical bug fixed in v2.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit <https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\> for migration path(s).
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.2: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@2.1.1: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated json3@3.3.2: Please use the native JSON object instead of JSON 3
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.5: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.0.4: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated sane@2.5.2: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-alpha.2: please switch to a stable version
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@9.0.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.2: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated buffer@4.9.1: This version of 'buffer' is out-of-date. You must update to v4.9.2 or newer
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.1.1: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.2: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.5.7: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\KOMP\AppData\Local\Temp\postinstall657856524548.cmd
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\KOMP\\Desktop\\ИД\\Обучение JS\\React\\Medium lvl\\Урок №2\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\KOMP\\Desktop\\ИД\\Обучение JS\\React\\Medium lvl\\Урок №2\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\KOMP\Desktop\ИД\Обучение JS\React\Medium lvl\Урок №2\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\KOMP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-15T03_40_32_651Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: требуется python2 или python в PATH

Comment: у меня стоит python 26

Comment: поставил python 2.8 версию, ошибки те же

Comment: а в cmd он вызывается как python2 или python28?

Comment: я установил 2.8, но CMD показывает 2.6.6 почему-то

Comment: не, я имею ввиду если вызвать команду `python2 --version` то она сработает или не найдёт программу?

Comment: Где вы 2.8 нашли, если последняя официальная версия 2.7.18?

Answer (score 0):

Проверь переменную окружения `PATH`, он не может найти в ней путь к экзешнику питона. Если пути там нет, то добавь вручную.

Чтобы переменная обновилась часто требуется перезапуск консоли

Comment: где найти эту переменную?

Comment: @Vladislav4488 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=windows+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+path